# How can I match these two elements after page refresh? - jsFiddle included

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, refresh

I'm using an imagemap to work along side checkboxes in a form on my app, I've managed to get the checkboxes to persist their checked state after page reload using the dumbformstate plugin. How can I make the areas of the imagemap act in the same way?

Currently if you select north or south the corresponding checkbox or imagemap area will also be selected but on submitting the form only the checkbox will appear to be checked, the area of the imagemap will return to its default style.

I'm also using jQuery-UI to style the checkboxes and the maphilight plugin to style the checked state of the imagemap areas.

http://jsfiddle.net/dRz9U/12/

Thanks for any help its much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, on page load, select the checkboxes that have been checked, and update the corresponding area:

http://jsfiddle.net/QVkmb/

Answer (score 0):

Just check which checkboxes has checked after page loading - http://jsfiddle.net/dRz9U/15/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm really bad with javascript so can't figure out how to tweak it but the new fiddle swaps the the effect so now only the area map persists and not the checkboxes too.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dRz9U/18/ - better? I inverted logic a little, so when you will click on map it will trigger label click and label click will change map highlight state